# Windows 2012 WebDAV "not installed", cannot enable feature

Tags: installation, webdav, windows-server-2012

I am following [this manual](http://advancedhomeserver.com/making-a-pc-a-secure-webdav-server/) and I also checked [this offical Microsoft ISS one](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/webdav) for installing WebDAV on my windows 2012 server. But the field that I need to check according to those manuals is not active (greyed out) and has a "Not installed" notice.

In the Server Manager I can select server roles. It looks like this:

[image]
*(From a german server, but you get the point)...*

I want to enable/install this feature and this is exactly what I expected to be able to do here. Everything on google on installing WebDAV points me to exactly the same spot.

What should I do to be able to enable/install WebDAV here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not have a root website on the domain configured.
I configured a default website like this:

[image]

After I did that the WevDAV checkbox became active and I could install it.